# How to split a string given a specific ruleset?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, loops

I am trying to solve a USACO problem called "Broken Necklace". In this problem, you are given a string and you have find the maximum possible continuous color beads.

I am trying to take my string and split them into subsets where each part has its own color. The 'w' character can be either red or blue but it has to be apart of red or blue character. It cannot be on its own.

For example:

```
arr = []
string = 'rwbwrr' 
#do something
arr = ["rw","bw","rr"]
```

I have tried creating a while loop in a for loop but that did not work.

```
new_necklace = "bbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwww"
arr = []
count = 0
for i in range(len(new_necklace)):
    count = i
    if new_necklace[i] == 'r' or new_necklace[i] == 'b':
        while new_necklace[count+1] == 'w':
            count += 1
    arr.append(new_necklace[i:count])
```

I am getting an index out of range error when I try this method and it has messed up output. The array should equal ["bb","rwr","b","r"....]

EDIT:
I have made some revisions to my code and I ended up with this.

```
arr = []
for i in range(len(new_necklace)):
    count = i+1
    if new_necklace[i] == 'w':
        continue
    if new_necklace[i] == 'r' or new_necklace[i] == 'b':
        while count < len(new_necklace):
            if new_necklace[count] == 'w' or new_necklace[count] == new_necklace[i]:
                count += 1
            else:
                break
    arr.append(new_necklace[i:count])
```

However, this causes a new problem as the array outputs `['bb', 'b', 'rwr', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'rr', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'rwrwwr', 'rwwr', 'r', 'bw', 'rwrr', 'rr', 'r', 'bwww']` even though the new_necklace is `"bbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwww"`. It seems to be appending the same subset twice.

Comment: `while new_necklace[count+1] == 'w':` -> `while count+1<len(new_necklace) and new_necklace[count+1] == 'w':` This change should fix the index out of range (only `i` was safe for indexing in your case, `count` was breaking for `w`'s at the end of the string). As for the output not behaving as expected, that's your part to debug. ;) I can give you a hint, though.

Comment: Do you mind helping me with the edited code?

Comment: Does 'w' mean white and all you have to do is find color beads?

Comment: Well 'w' is white, but it can be red or blue depending on which creates the higher sequence. This problem statement should help, https://train.usaco.org/usacoprob2?a=Ar8znq1wddp&S=beads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re` module to split string according the rules:

```
s = 'bbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwww'

import re

print([i[0] for i in re.findall(r'(([rb])(?:\2|w)*)', s)])
```

Prints:

```
['bb', 'rwr', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'rr', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'rwrwwr', 'bw', 'rwrr', 'bwww']
```

Comment: Very cool! Is there a way of doing this without importing modules?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that 'w' means white and after removing that you have to find the maximum stretch of coloured beads. If that is correct, below is a solution, else I am sorry I read it wrong. As an example, I have taken the bead as "bbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwww".

```py
import numpy as np
new_necklace = "bbrwrbrbrrbrbrwrwwrbwrwrrbwww"
Split_necklace = new_necklace.split("w")
Max_Bead = np.array([len(x) for x in Split_necklace])
max_color_string = Split_necklace[np.argmax(Max_Bead)]
print(max_color_string)
```

This prints for me the below string.

```sh
rbrbrrbrbr
```

Please let me know if this is anywhere close to what you wanted. Thank you.